# Unable to run test on gitlab pipeline due to DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver, maven, linux

I created a sample Selenium Webdriver test using java and maven and pushed it out to my gitlab repository. Then I created a  new pipeline to run the automated tests. This is my first time running a test on the pipeline so I followed some instructions online. The issue I'm having is that the test fails because of this error: `(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)`

I saw some few questions regarding this too and tried to add those solutions but still getting that error. Used this link where I added those arguments.
[WebDriverException: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist while trying to initiate Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t/50642913#50642913)

Not sure what I need to do to fix this error or how to run the test as a non-root user which can maybe be a workaround.

This is my yml file for the pipeline

```
# calling the docker image where chrome, maven, jdk are available to run the tests
image: markhobson/maven-chrome:jdk-11

# building the maven
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile

# running the tests
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - mvn clean test
```

BaseTest class

```
@BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite()  {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        String runTime = null;
        
        try {
            InputStream input = BaseTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("runSetup.properties");
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(input);
            runTime = properties.getProperty("runTimeOnLocal");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // if it's true, that means running locally on my machine and open the webrowser
        // if it's false, that means it's running on gitlab headless        
        if(runTime.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE")) {
            options.addArguments("start-maximized"); 
            options.addArguments("enable-automation"); 
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
            options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--disable-browser-side-navigation"); 
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
        }
        else if(runTime.equalsIgnoreCase("FALSE")) {
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox"); 
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu"); 
            options.setHeadless(true);
        }
        
        driver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));
        Log.info("Opening web application");
        driver.get().get("https://demo.opencart.com/");
    }
```

I also put the link to my repo as this is a sample for me to review selenium (need to switch to master branch)

[SeleniumReview](https://gitlab.com/nasim.ahmed2193/seleniumreview.git)

Answer (score 0):

DevTool error is often associated with non compatible version of chrome and chromedriver.

make sure your browser , driver and OS are compatible . Download the correct OS for the gtilab OS and browser types and versions